# Shear along an edge loop maintaining radial geometry?

Tags: modeling

Does anyone know if there is a way to shear the selected faces using the edge loop at the bottom for each of the faces, maintaining the radial shape of the object as a whole? [image: Original Picture] The image without the faces selected is the desired affect I wish to achieve, without using booleans. [image: Desired Effect]

Comment: Shear doesn't seem to work in your case, but you can move your edge, and then easily give some correction on the top face

Comment: So there's no tool or operation in blender that can move faces above the bottom ring forwards by varying amounts depending on distance? seems like it's a loss not having a tool like that.